# Check variable is like a value from another variable in PHP

Tags: php

I need to check the value of `$variable1` is `LIKE` another variable2.

There could be something else after a dash but i can't predict what.  Is there any kind of wildcard idea in PHP like sql? `LIKE variable%` ?

Comment: This is a case for `preg_match()`

Comment: do you just want to know if `"foo"` is part of `"foo-bar"` or anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to know if one string is part of another, then do use

- [`strpos`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) - Find position of first occurrence of a string

because *[(quoting the PHP Manual on `preg_match`)](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)*

> Do not use `preg_match()` if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use `strpos()` or `strstr()` instead as they will be faster.

**Example:**

```
$haystack = 'foo-bar';
$needle   = 'o-b';
echo (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== FALSE) ? 'yeah' : 'no';
```

will output "yeah" because "o-b" is a substring in"foo-bar"

Answer (score 2):

If you mean `variable%` literally (to match the beginning of a string), this is a case for [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/preg_match).

Slightly modified example from the manual:

```
$subject = "This string begins with This";
$pattern = '/^This/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

use the `/i` modifier for case insensitive search.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's a more robust option:

```
function isLike($haystack, $needle) {
    $regex = '#^'.preg_quote($needle, '#').'$#i';
    //add support for wildcards
    $regex = str_replace(array('%', '_'), array('.*?', '.?'), $regex);
    return 0 != preg_match($regex, $haystack);
}
```

Basically, it operates just like MySQL's LIKE.  It uses `%` as a "any character, any number of times" and `_` as "anycharacter, zero or one time".

Here's some examples:

```
isLike('foobarbaz', 'fooba_ba_'); // true
isLike('foobarbaz', 'ba_ba_'); // false
isLike('foobarbaz', 'foodar'); // false
isLike('foobarbaz', 'foo%baz'); // true
isLike('foobarbaz', '%bar%'); // true
```

Comment: why would I want to introduce that syntax over normal regex or fnmatch?

Comment: @Gordon: Well, perhaps for user inputted filter/search criteria?

Comment: @Gordon it has the advantage of, as it says, allowing mySQL `%` syntax at any point in the string, which is nice, say for user input or centrally stored search string. +1

Answer (score 1):

Yet another alternative is to use

- [`fnmatch()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) - checks if the passed string would match the given shell wildcard pattern.

Disregard that it says filename in the Manual. It will match anything you throw at it.

*Example:*

```
echo fnmatch('foo*', 'foo-bar') ? 'yeah' : 'no';
echo fnmatch('foo-b?r', 'foo-bar') ? 'yeah' : 'no';
```

would both return "yeah".

Comment: @ircmaxell please see changelog notes: 5.3.0 This function is now available on Windows platforms. But with 5.3 not widely available yet, I agree it's a (minor) caveat.

Comment: Quite fair, sorry about that (removed comment)

Comment: @ircmaxell why? It was a fair comment. It **is** a caveat.